# The entity type 'EntityQueryable<Entrys>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a scenario, I have users submitting entries to an API endpoint and a flag is updated as 1 on the database. A user can submit more than entry as per there feel and need per time. I have a logic that checks if an entry already exists, and if a user submits another form, the previous form is set to 0 and the new form is set to 1. Whenever I submit a second entry I end up with an error

> The entity type 'EntityQueryable' was not found. Ensure that
> the entity type has been added to the model.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetOrCreateEntry(Object
> entity)

this is my logic for checking

```
public async Task<Entrys> AddEntrys(Entrys entrys)
        {

            var pastSurveys = _context.Entrys.Where(e => e.UpdatedBy == entrys.UpdatedBy && e.Month == entrys.Month
           && e.Day == entrys.Day && e.Year == entrys.Year && e.CurrentStatus==true).AsQueryable();

            if (pastSurveys.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (Entrys e in pastSurveys)
                {
                    if (e.CurrentStatus == true)
                    {
                        e.CurrentStatus = false;
                    }
                }
                _context.Add(pastSurveys);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            entrys.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            _context.Add(entrys);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return entrys;
        }
```

How can I have my logic to keep on checking the existing surveys and updating them to 0 while new ones are set to 1 without getting the error above, Have tried researching no luck do far. Thank you in advance

Comment: Instead of `.AsQueryable()` change to `ToList()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem that instead of Updating entities you inserts them. Also you do not need two `SaveChanges` calls. `pastSurveys.Count()` also executes unwanted query.

Corrected method:

```cs
public async Task<Entrys> AddEntrys(Entrys entrys)
{
    var pastSurveys = _context.Entrys
        .Where(e => e.UpdatedBy == entrys.UpdatedBy && e.Month == entrys.Month
            && e.Day == entrys.Day && e.Year == entrys.Year && e.CurrentStatus == true)
        .ToList();

    foreach (Entrys e in pastSurveys)
    {
        e.CurrentStatus = false;
    }
    
    entrys.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    _context.Add(entrys);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return entrys;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @arrif from your implementation

change the _`context.Add(pastSurveys);` to `_context.UpdateRange(pastSurveys);`

From your current setup you adding instead of updating the flag. Try that and tell if it works cheers

Comment: Actually with EF Core you do not need to call `UpdateRange` at all.

Comment: I know that this works, but just remove `UpdateRange` and it will work too. Also Change `AsQueryable` to `ToList`, because you are firing two queries to SQL Server - bad for performance.

Comment: Instead of update range I change to what @SvyatoslavDanyliv?

Comment: Do nothing, change objects properties and then call `SaveChanges`. ChangeTracker will find changed objects and should send updates automatically.